# How to visualise multigraph using networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.MultiGraph(strict = False)
G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,2)
```

How to draw the multi graph using networkx (display multiple edges also)